# What will be the way to give user public access to check their contribution?

Tags: civimail, civievent, civicontribute, civimember, contribution-page

What will be the best way to give event registrant to check their payment and contribution status through an public front end form?

Is an email address with CAPTCHA authentication field appropriate to grantee the give access to real user preventing others/spammers?

The reason to do this through an extension is to give partial payment feature and refund request feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Contact Dashboard is a good way to show people their information.

Usually people need to login, you may be able to use a token to allow people to see it without logging in (not sure) but if payments are involved I would recommend people should have to login.

Answer (score 2):

As Sanjay suggests you can use a checksum email, but requiring login is best.  You should not need CAPTHCA.    This presentation from CiviCON Denver 2015 "[Frontend Partial Payments](http://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/frontend-partial-payments-development-framework)"

The framework should be available in GIT