# Deposit payment

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor

I have problems on how to manage payments. 
The entry fee is € 190.00 that can be paid or all or a deposit of 80.00 €. 
How do I know who I still have to pay?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using CiviCRM Events???

Comment: I have not yet figured out what is best to use.

Comment: can you please explain me what you are trying to do with some screen shots

Comment: I manage a basketball club. I must record the annual payments. Players can pay:
1. all in one tranche, € 190.00. With a discount of € 10.00 (€ 180.00)
2. give a deposit of 80.00 € and then in November, € 110.00 (€ 190.00)

Thanks.

Comment: you can not make partial payment in membership so you have to decide a different work flow for recording this payment

Comment: Ok, if you use events? Every year is a sports event for me.

Comment: if you are looking after just little data and if you are alright with doing manual process then i can suggest a way but requires manual processing. also do you need reports for accountant ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29492/discussion-between-ramesh-and-marco-mapelli).

Comment: OK. what can i do?

Answer (score 4):

Marco --

Partial payment from the front end is not yet available in CiviCRM, but it can be done through the extension described in this CiviCON presentation "[Front End Partial payments](http://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/frontend-partial-payments-development-framework)"

It's avaialble in Github.

Your use case is similar to this situation:
[What will be the way to give user public access to check their contribution?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/what-will-be-the-way-to-give-user-public-access-to-check-their-contribution/5205#5205)